# How to prove this proposal about Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose we have an irreducible Markov chain and the process takes finite possible values $(0, 1, \dots, N)$, then there exist $ C < \infty $, $\rho < 1$, so that

$P (X_{m} \neq j,m = 0, 1, \dots,n | X_{0} = i) \leqq C\rho^{n} $

I barely have no ideas about the proof, willing to get some insights.

Comment: What if there was an $\epsilon>0$ such that the probability of visiting state $j$ sometime in the next 20 steps was at least $\epsilon>0$, regardless of the current state?

Comment: @Michael I think you are right but can you show it in details